# How to use “list” of python to add a new column with finding the corresponding relationship between the elements ？

Tags: python, algorithm

The description of the problem is：

Now we have `list1` and `list2`. Their number of rows and columns is not fixed, but they have the same number of rows，So we can add `list2` to `list1` as new columns. Note, however, that the list we use is essentially a one-dimensional array, except that the elements in the list are tuple... They look like two-dimensional arrays, but they don't.They are essentially one-dimensional lists.

Sample questions：

```
list1= [("A","the first",1,"one"),("B","the second",2,"two"),("C","the third",3,"three"),("D","the 4th",4,"four")]
list2 = [("C","cat","animal" ),("B","banana","fruit"),("A","apple","fruit") ,("D","do","verb")  ]
```

Sample output:

```
[("A","the first",1,"one","apple","fruit"),
("B","the second",2,"two","banana","fruit" ),
("C","the third",3,"three","cat","animal" ),
("D","the 4th",4,"four","do","verb")]
```

Note that the number of columns in `list1` and `list2` is not fixed, and the number of rows must be equal. You can use column 0 in `list1` as a reference to merge lsit1 and List2. And you need to get rid of the duplicate columns.

I know that this simple algorithm can be written in any case. How to make the whole algorithm concise and clever?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1= [("A","the first",1,"one"),("B","the second",2,"two"),("C","the third",3,"three"),("D","the 4th",4,"four")]
list2 = [("C","cat","animal" ),("B","banana","fruit"),("A","apple","fruit") ,("D","do","verb") ]

d = defaultdict(lambda: list())

for column, *rest_cols in list1+list2:
    d[column] += [c for c in rest_cols if c not in d[column]]  # can also made with |= set(rest_cols) and d as defaultdict of set() but the order won't maintained

output = [(k, *v) for k, v in d.items()]  # converting back to the required list of tuples
print(output)
```

gives:

```
[('A', 'the first', 1, 'one', 'apple', 'fruit'), ('B', 'the second', 2, 'two', 'banana', 'fruit'), ('C', 'the third', 3, 'three', 'cat', 'animal'), ('D', 'the 4th', 4, 'four', 'do', 'verb')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple zip() application with the added twist that your lists are not ordered to match at the index level:

```
list1 = [("A","the first",1,"one"),("B","the second",2,"two"),("C","the third",3,"three"),("D","the 4th",4,"four")]
list2 = [("C","cat","animal" ),("B","banana","fruit"),("A","apple","fruit") ,("D","do","verb")  ]

result = [ a+b[1:] for a,b in zip(sorted(list1),sorted(list2)) ]

for row in result:print(row)

('A', 'the first', 1, 'one', 'apple', 'fruit')
('B', 'the second', 2, 'two', 'banana', 'fruit')
('C', 'the third', 3, 'three', 'cat', 'animal')
('D', 'the 4th', 4, 'four', 'do', 'verb')
```

However, I would suggest using dictionaries instead of lists of tuples for this kind of "keyed" structure.